# How to animate a grid in Flutter similar to AnimateList?

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I am trying to implement a grid animation similar to what's shown in the gif below.

[image]

I know of `AnimateList` widget which does a similar thing for lists. However, I want to implement it for a GridView and AnimateList doesn't let me specify the column count per row.

Is there a package or plugin that let's me implement the desired animation on change of the underlying data structures's state, such as, on updated search/updated filter or sort criteria? Or how else do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this package called [shaky_animated_listview](https://pub.dev/packages/shaky_animated_listview) in pub.dev, it provides an animation called `Shaking Grid` which look like the following:

[image: Shaking Grid Animation]

The above animation can be implemented easily like the following:

```
GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    // shrinkWrap: true,
    children: List.generate(9, (i) => GridAnimatorWidget(
        child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey,
                ),
        ),
    ),
    ),).toList()
)
```

Comment: I am looking for the animation on a change of state, not particularly during loading the screen. When the value of the underlying data structure (list) changes, I want an animation wherein the grid tiles move to take up new position.

Comment: I think it will also work because when the state changes (items on the Grid), the Grid would rebuild so the animation will start over as in the example image, give it a try.